# How to update database from other site periodically using php?

Tags: php, jquery

Say my site lists items from other sites, for example, I listed ebay items, what I want to do is when the ebay items be sold out the corresponding item info on my site can be updated, how can we do this using php?

Of course we can start a scheduled process on the hosting server, however we don't have privilege to do that for we only have spaces to host php and mysql.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: How is jQuery related to your issue?

Comment: Maybe jQuery has the timer to do this.

Comment: You certainly need jQuery for this. Search for some plugin to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't run CRON on your server, then you can have another server run it for you. As long as your database is accessible to the outside, you can run some CRON from another server or run an application (like a NodeJS script) to grab the external site's data and update your database.

Or better: Find a hosting space that allows CRON jobs or ask your admin for that privilege.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script that runs when you open the url to it, and then you open the URL yourself on specific times. I suppose you could even automate that on your desktop computer.
Another option is to write a PHP script that loops and sleeps for an x amount of time, say 8 hours, and loops again to import the data.

Comment: Thanks, about the php script that runs loop, where I can put the php script? and how can it be invoked?

Comment: You could just invoke it by opening it in a browser, or via a command line if you have the access (look into PHP CLI)

Answer (score 0):

**You need to set up cron job.**

You can use free service like: https://www.setcronjob.com/

You set up create special page, accessed by cron service which do all the work (list ebay items, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

well say we carry on with the ebay example. would need direct database connection details to the ebay DB Or there would need to be an API to that data. If there was an API you could check every page load like most websites.

Comment: Check every page on load will not be so efficient I think, and it will degrade the load process.

Comment: right well a cron job is what you want then, depending how often you want the data updates depends how often you set the cron job to run